# How to create an absolutely positioned submenu which appears on css hover

Tags: css

I have a menu which needs to expand to show the child elements on hover. According to the design the expanded child ul needs to expand across the full width of the page so needs to be absolutely positioned in order to break out from the width of the parent li.

The problem is that I need the child ul to remain visible as you hover over it. Because it is absolutely positioned it no longer contained by the parent li, so as soon as my mouse moves off that it disappears.

If I change the parent li to position:relative the ul remains visible when the mouse moves over it, but the child ul no longer fills 100% width of the page.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/sx2aouht/12/

Here is abbreviated markup (full code on the fiddle link above):

```
<nav class="priority-nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-178 help"><a href="/content/help-advice" title="" class="active-trail active">Help &amp; Advice</a>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-526"><a href="/content/find-your-local-services" title="">Find your local services</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-mlid-528"><a href="/node" title="">Join CarerSmart</a></li>
                <li class="leaf menu-mlid-527"><a href="/node" title="">Join our online community</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the css:

```
.priority-nav ul li {
   //if this is uncommented the ul will remain visible when
   //the mouse is over it, but the ul will not fill the page 100%
   //position: relative;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 10px;
   list-style-type: none;
 }

.priority-nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 130px;
}

.priority-nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try: `padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;` instead for your `.priority-nav ul li`?

Comment: I can't see how that helps as the issue is the child ul needs to fill the whole width of the page.

Comment: One solution is to use js to calculate the page width and then set the width of the child ul to that in px. But I'd prefer to avoid js if there is a suitable css solution

Comment: you said: The problem is that I need the child ul to remain visible as you hover over it. -  the extra padding fixed that part. Not a complete answer, so a comment :)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now (and from the answer below too). Am just seeing if I can add the extra padding without impacting on the design elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The menu already stays open when you hover the submenu, the problem is that when the mouse goes down to the submenu, it leaves the hovered li element, in order to avoid this make sure that when the mouse enters the submenu, it will not leave the main li you hover, the submenu is in the li item, so hovering it is considered hovering the main li.

You just have to avoid leaving the main li until you enter the submenu, I used some padding in your example:

```css
.priority-nav ul li {
   //if this is uncommented the ul will remain visible when
   //the mouse is over it, but the ul will not fill the page 100%
   //position: relative;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 10px 5px;
   list-style-type: none;
 }

.priority-nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 130px;
}

.priority-nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="priority-nav">
  <ul class="menu"><li class="first expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-178 help"><a href="/content/help-advice" title="" class="active-trail active">Help &amp; Advice</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-526"><a href="/content/find-your-local-services" title="">Find your local services</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-528"><a href="/node" title="">Join CarerSmart</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-527"><a href="/node" title="">Join our online community</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-530"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 4</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-531"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 5</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-532"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 6</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-533"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 7</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-534"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 8</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-535"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 9</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="expanded menu-mlid-184 community"><a href="/node" title="">Online Community</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-536"><a href="/node" title="">Discussion board</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-537"><a href="/node" title="">Chat</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="last expanded menu-mlid-176 get-involved"><a href="/node" title="">Get Involved</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf menu-mlid-529"><a href="/node" title="">Donate</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-538"><a href="/node" title="">Events</a></li>
<li class="leaf menu-mlid-539"><a href="/node" title="">Volunteer</a></li>
<li class="last leaf menu-mlid-540"><a href="/node" title="">Corporate opportunities</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li class="more"><a href=""><span>More</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks I think this solves the problem, as long as I can sort out the impact of the extra padding on the menu layout.

Comment: Kudos to @Aravona who suggested the same solution in a comment.

Comment: You can up vote his comment to give him well deserved reputation :) as for the positioning, it is good to add padding on both the top and bottom of a link, it makes it easier to click, the user no longer has to hit the text exactly and can miss by a few pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If the submenu is to be 100% width of the ***page*** but the top-level menu is not then we can still position the submenu in relation to the parent menu and not the `li`.

```
.priority-nav >.menu {
  position: relative;
}
```

But we size the submenu to the width of the page with viewport units.

```
.priority-nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
```

}

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  /* clearfix */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
.priority-nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
}
.priority-nav > .menu {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
.priority-nav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
.priority-nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
}
.priority-nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="priority-nav">
  <ul class="menu cf">
    <li class="first expanded active-trail active menu-mlid-178 help"><a href="/content/help-advice" title="" class="active-trail active">Help &amp; Advice</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-526"><a href="/content/find-your-local-services" title="">Find your local services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-528"><a href="/node" title="">Join CarerSmart</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-527"><a href="/node" title="">Join our online community</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-530"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-531"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 5</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-532"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 6</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-533"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 7</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-534"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 8</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-535"><a href="/node" title="">Help and advice topic 9</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded menu-mlid-184 community"><a href="/node" title="">Online Community</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-536"><a href="/node" title="">Discussion board</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-537"><a href="/node" title="">Chat</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="last expanded menu-mlid-176 get-involved"><a href="/node" title="">Get Involved</a>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf menu-mlid-529"><a href="/node" title="">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-538"><a href="/node" title="">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf menu-mlid-539"><a href="/node" title="">Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last leaf menu-mlid-540"><a href="/node" title="">Corporate opportunities</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="more"><a href=""><span>More</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It's not clear from the simplified code above but the ..menu does not fill the full width of the page in the actual code i am working with, so unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: Because the full code is in the context of lots of other elements  in a site and I was trying to break the problem down to its essentials. Thanks for your suggestion but in this case it didn't work.